# If function using future arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, boolean

I have an np.array with multiple arrays within.

```
bool_window[0] = (256,1)
```

in this case i have 40 arrays of (256,1). The data within the array is either 0 or 1 and i want to use this code to check if the next array has more 1 than the one before.

```
for i in bool_window:
    if (np.count_nonzero(i) > 0)  and (np.count_nonzero(i) < 256) and np.count_nonzero(i) < np.count_nonzero(i+1):
        print('In this array there are ', np.count_nonzero(i), ' events')
```

The problem is that np.count_nonzero(i+1) is not working properly. Is there a way to say that the next array needs to be bigger than the actual one?

```
0 256
0 256
0 256
50 256
178 256
174 256
46 256
0 256
0 256
0 256
```

This is the output i get with this code.

```
for i in bool_window:
   if np.count_nonzero(i) < np.count_nonzero(i+1):
            print(np.count_nonzero(i), np.count_nonzero(i+1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data contains only `1` and `0` you can just use `np.sum`:

```
bool_window = np.stack(bool_window)  # In case you have 40 arrays of shape (256, 1).
n_ones = bool_window.sum(axis=(-2, -1))
has_more_ones = n_ones[1:] > n_ones[:-1]
```

Comment: I dont get it to run. I cannot make a np.sum of arrays within an array

Comment: @Bleistift Well I assumed that you have *one* array of shape `(40, 256, 1)`. If instead you have 40 arrays of shape `(256, 1)` then you can use `bool_window = np.stack(bool_window)` beforehand.

Comment: I think that could work. How do you add more to the True/False statement?
So that only the first one is true as in the function i used above? 
has_more_once = (n_ones[1:] > n_ones[:-1]) and (n_ones[1:] != 0) and (n_ones[1:] <128)

Comment: Found it np.logical_and(). Thanks for the help!